# Charging a Li-ion battery with a Buck Convertor & ATmega8

Tags: batteries, mosfet, buck, lithium-ion, charger

I'm trying to charge a 7.4 V Li-Ion battery following the CC/CV protocol and have a few questions.

I want to use an SMPS from my old laptop that can provide 20 V/3.25 A and feed that to a buck convertor and to the battery. To prevent the battery from overcharging and to limit the current to 0.5C or maybe even lower, is it possible to control the MOSFET of the buck (with PWM from the ATmega) measuring my current from a current sensor and the voltage from the battery?
Then adjust the PWM to not exceed a predetermined current in the CC mode and after that, limit the voltage similarly in the CV mode?

Comment: Yes, all of this can be done. You just need to design the circuits and write the code.

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/id/Microcontroller-Based-Smart-Battery-Charger/

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thank you sir. That is approximately what I had in mind too. My doubts are with the drive of the P-MOSFET. In order to drive the transistor, I see that the author used a voltage divider and a BJT. From my understanding, the BJT is used to increase the pin current of the MCU, but why is the pin voltage divided using that voltage divider? Wouldn't the MOSFET conduct if I simply write 1 to the MCU pin and supply 5V? From the IRF9540 datasheet I see that driving it requires a gate voltage of between (-2,-4)? Could you please maybe help me trying to understand the working of MOS?

Comment: @aluionescu I recommend to write a new question with more specific content, as this one will be closed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the circuit referred to by Bruce Abbott.
Copied from [here](https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/FLR/Q7GK/IL2C7DFQ/FLRQ7GKIL2C7DFQ.pdf)
and part of [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Microcontroller-Based-Smart-Battery-Charger/) "Instructable.

> ... My doubts are with the drive of the P-MOSFET. In order to drive the transistor, I see that the author used a voltage divider and a BJT. From my understanding, the BJT is used to increase the pin current of the MCU, but why is the pin voltage divided using that voltage divider?

There are two P MOSFETS. They are named - using names helps people answer questions more easily and reliably - here, Q1.  Similarly specifying R2 & R10 helps people to zero in on your question.

When the microcontroller (U4) starts the state of pin 17 which drives the MOSFET Q1's gate is undefined. Without R10 the gate may float high and allow Q1 to turn on unintentionally.
Q4 does not have a similar pulldown (but ideally should have) but, as long as Q1 is off initially the state of Q3 is less important.

In your case, having Q1 and Q3 on or partially on unintentionally could apply 20V to a 7.4V nominal LiIon battery. Magic smoke may then be emitted by some or all of Q1 Q3 D1 U3, the battery and maybe other components as well. This is unlikely to be desirable :-).

[image]

Comment: So do you think that this circuit is likely to damage the battery if the MCU doesn't properly turn off the transistors? The author did mention that he added Q3 because even when the MCU OCR register was initialized to 0 (in order for the PWM to be 0) on the gate of Q1 there was still some voltage on the out of the buck and that including Q3 solved the problem.

Comment: @aluionescu "Do I think ..." -> !!!!!!!! Putting 20V in and having a 7.2V nominal LiIon battery on the output had better work properly or ... wow !

Comment: FWIW You can but buck converters on AliExpress and ebay and .... for LESS than the cost of the components that do most of this task. Adding a little extra control and some extra protection should make an easier and probably better device. I would do it from scratch only if either a learning exercise or as a design I as making vast quantities of.

Comment: Yes, that is my main reason - to do it as a learning exercise.

Comment: @aluionescu Consider a solid 9V or so zener across the battery preceded by a fuse ! :-).